# if characters in word then do an action only once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a python hangman game that works fine except for one logical error associated with counting how many failed attempts are there.

```
    failed = 0
    for char in word:
        if char in letter_guess:
            print(char, end="")
            if letter_guess == word:
                print("")
                print('CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WON')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            failed = failed + 1
            print('_ ', end="")
            if failed == 15:
                print("GAME OVER! your word was", word)
                sys.exit()
```

instead of adding just one when the player guesses a wrong letter it adds one for every letter that is not the letter that the player guessed. For example if the word is 'star' and a player guesses the letter 'e' then the program will add 4 to failed; one for each letter. I'm not sure how I can fix that so that it only does this specific function once because i still need it to add a '_' for every wrong letter. I thought maybe I could multiply the number of tries by 4 for 4 letter words but I'm not sure if that will work.

here's the full code

```
import random
import time
import sys

# GAME INTRODUCTION
print('HANGMAN')
name = input('Username: ')
print('Welcome', name, 'are you ready to play?')
answer = ''
print("type 'start' to begin")
while answer != 'start':
    time.sleep(0.7)
    answer = input()
print("OK! Let's begin")
print("pick the mode/difficulty of the game")
time.sleep(0.7)
print("1-Easy")
print("2-Medium")
print("3-Difficult")

# POSSIBLE WORDS IN GAME
words_4 = ['time', 'king', 'song', 'disk', 'meal',
           'cell', 'hair', 'menu', 'math']
words_5 = ['world', 'paper', 'hotel', 'queen', 'uncle',
           'night', 'hotel', 'shirt', 'pizza']
words_6 = ['person', 'tennis', 'camera', 'sector',
           'potato', 'safety', 'growth', 'thanks']


# CHOOSING GAME DIFFICULTY
mode = str(input())

if mode in ['Easy', '1', 'easy']:
    word_list = words_4
    letter_num = 4
    print("your word consists of 4 letters")
elif mode in ['Medium', '2', 'medium']:
    word_list = words_5
    letter_num = 5
    print("your word consists of 5 letters")
elif mode in ['Difficult', '3', 'difficult']:
    word_list = words_6
    letter_num = 6
    print("your word consists of 6 letters")
else:
    print("Mode does not exist!")

number = 0
i = 0
dash = ('_ ')
word = random.choice(word_list)
for char in word:
    i = i + 1
for number in range(i):
    print(dash, end="")
failed = 0
guessed = ('')
print("")

#CHECKING CHARACTER PLAYER INPUTTED
tries = True
while tries is True:
    print("")
    print("")
    letter_guess = input('Guess any letter: ')
    for char in word:
        if char in letter_guess:
            print(char, end="")
            if letter_guess == word:
                print("")
                print('CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WON')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            
            print('_ ', end="")
            if failed == 15:
                print("GAME OVER! your word was", word)
                sys.exit()
```

Comment: Add `break` at the bottom of the `else` so it exits the loop after the first failure

Comment: I cannot do that since i need the code to add a dash in place of every failed letter so that way the player knows where the letter they picked is in the sentence. for example if the word was star and they picked 't' then the output would be '-t--' but if i break the loop the output is just ''–"

Comment: What is in `letter_guess`?

Comment: letter_guess is the players input or the letter the payer guessed

Comment: You are trying to do things in the for loop that don't belong there. Put `if letter_guess not in word: failed += 1` outside of the for loop. Also the win and lose condition. The for loop is only useful for printing the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple issues in your code.

1. The player will never win since `letter_guess == word` will only be true if the word has only one letter or the user is able to enter more than one letter each turn, and I don't think that's the idea here.
2. In failed you are not counting attempts but counting missing letters. In other words, you are counting '_' in every attempt.

I will left you here some fixed to your code so you can use it as reference:

```
# You have to sore the good guesses.
good_letters = []
print("")

#CHECKING CHARACTER PLAYER INPUTTED
tries = True
while tries is True:
    print("")
    print("")
    letter_guess = input('Guess any letter: ')
    

    # You already know here if is a failed attempt ..
    # if the guess is not in the word, increment failed otherwise
    # store the letter as a good guess.
    if letter_guess in word:
        good_letters.append(letter_guess)
    else:
        failed += 1

    # And if you get to 15 ... you loose.
    if failed == 15:
        print("GAME OVER! your word was", word)
        sys.exit()

    # If all the letter from the word have been correctly guessed, the user have win.
    win = all([letter in good_letters for letter in word])
    if win:
        print("")
        print('CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WON')
        sys.exit()

    # This it is just for printing output to the user.
    for char in word:
        # If a letter of the word have been correctly guessed ...
        if char in good_letters:
            # ... print it.

            # Adding a space after char here will make the ouput better.
            print(char + " ", end="")
        else:
            print('_ ', end="")
```

Comment: thank you very much im very happy with how it works, though i dont understand the append function but anyways thank you so much again it works really well

Comment: @RäžãnĞhâñëm, the append function is a function of the list, the only thing it does is add a new item to the list. and the `all` function checks that all items in some iterable are True.  Glad to help, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You has to exit your loop when count the first bad word. Use break at the end

[EDIT] Then maybe this

```py
    flag = True
    failed = 0
    for char in word:
        if char in letter_guess:
            print(char, end="")
            if letter_guess == word:
                print("")
                print('CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WON')
                sys.exit()
        else:
            if flag:
                failed = failed + 1
                flag = False
            print('_ ', end="")
            if failed == 15:
                print("GAME OVER! your word was", word)
                sys.exit() 
            break
```

Just make sure that `flag = True` is always actualized

Comment: I cannot do that since i need the code to add a dash in place of every failed letter so that way the player knows where the letter they picked is in the sentence. for example if the word was star and they picked 't' then the output would be '_t_ _' but if i break the loop the output is just '_'

Comment: it still doesn't work. i added the full code to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I make a small changes to your code, instead of increase the failed in loop, you must put it outside the `for` loop, but still inside the `while` loop.

and you need to put `sys.exit()` outside the `while` loop, because you use `while Tries is True`, you can put `Tries = False` inside the `for` loop if the letter guess is all correct and 1 more outside the `for` loop if the `failure = 15`,

hope this is what you tried to achieve

```
tries = True
while tries is True:
    print("")
    print("")
    letter_guess = input('Guess any letter: ')
    is_failed = False
    for char in word:
        if char in letter_guess:
            print(char, end="")
            if letter_guess == word:
                print("")
                print('CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WON')
                tries = False
                break
        else:
            is_failed = True
            print('_ ', end="")

    if is_failed:
        failed = failed + 1
        is_failed = False

    if failed == 15:
        print('')
        print('')
        print("GAME OVER! your word was", word)
        tries = False

sys.exit()
```

If you want to store the previous answer, and make your code a bit more cleaner:

```
tries = True
guessed_word = ['_' for _ in range(len(word))]
while tries is True:
    print("")
    print("")
    letter_guess = input('Guess any letter: ')

    is_failed = False

    for i, char in enumerate(word):
        if char in letter_guess:
            guessed_word[i] = char
        else:
            is_failed = True

    print(' '.join(guessed_word))

    if is_failed:
        failed = failed + 1
        is_failed = False

    if failed == 15:
        print('')
        print("GAME OVER! your word was", word)
        tries = False

    if '_' not in guessed_word:
        print("")
        print('CONGRATULATIONS! YOU WON')
        tries = False

sys.exit()
```

Comment: @RäžãnĞhâñëm, no, it does not, with this code the user never wins. and also the correctly guessed letters are not shown to the user after the first time the letter is guessed.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda the user wins if they type the full word

Comment: @RäžãnĞhâñëm Glad I can help you :)

Comment: @RaydelMiranda i couldnt find a way to get around the letters disappearing but i didnt think it was a big issue since the player would know where the letters are

Comment: @RäžãnĞhâñëm if you want to keep the letters, you can put them in `list`, lets say the answer is STAR, then you need to initialize an empty list `['_', '_', '_', '_']`, but everytime the player input the correct letter, it will stored in the list. lets say the player input A, which means the list will be updated to `['_', '_', 'A', '_']`. Hope you get the idea

Comment: @RäžãnĞhâñëm I post an answer with the code you need for that, it is up to you at the end it is your game :)  .  I was only suggesting improvements to the code and the logic of the game. When playing hangman, the player it is not suppose to guess the entire word at a time. Just saying.